# Notepad++ doesn't show Russian letters

Tags: notepad++, encoding, language

I'm trying to setup the translation file (`.php`) but can't get Notepad++ to display the Russian text. The file was created on a PC with *Russian Windows 7* (Windows Notepad) and everything looks fine there.

I sent it to my *PC EN Windows 7* and this is what I see:

```
Ñïàñèáî çà Âàø èíòåğåñ ê ğåêëàìå íà
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Notepad will save the text using ANSI encoding. This will use the default character set on the source computer and means that unless your other computer has the same character set you won't see the same results. The solution is to save your file in a universal encoding, either Unicode or UTF-8. These encodings map the Russian characters to the Unicode standard so are independent of any default character set on your, or anyone elses, computer.

From Notepad choose **File->Save As...** and pick Unicode or UTF-8.

[image]

Then when you open the file on any other computer it should display as intended.

Note: You only need to do this once for each new file. Since the file has now been marked as Unicode/UTF-8 (with a Byte Object Marker - BOM) Notepad and Notepad++ will recognize the BOM and keep the file in the same encoding.

Comment: Windows now defaults to using UCS-2LE (UTF-16) as the encoding.  NOTEPAD will read the file correctly.  @Teo is talking about Notepad++.  As the file came from a Russian system, it's almost certainly ALREADY a Unicode (UTF-8 or UTF-16) file, depending on the Windows version of the Russian system.Notepad++ can display Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc. just fine.  It's Russian it has the problem with, even when the files are already Unicode.

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Encoding`  menu and click on : **Convert to ANSI** . then again go to  `Encoding`  menu and click on **Encode in UTF-8 without BOM**

Comment: @teo Can you pass me your file ? zip it and upload it so I can test it myself. I've done what I said and it works all the time

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. All I get is another code with letters and numbers like "xCAxE7xE0". Do you know why?

Comment: it shows those characters because of its encoding!

Comment: @t pas me the file and one screen shot of what it should be like

Comment: +1 Thanks for trying, I tried the solution from "snowdude" as well and it worked for me. I will upvote your asnswer as soon as I have the 15 point I need to... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of displaying a [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)-encoded file with a [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)-like encoding.

Solution: Open the file with encoding `Windows-1251`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the supposedly Russian text file with MS-Word.  Before it opens, Word will indicate the encoding language, unless you have to select it from a list (e.g. UTF-8, Windows cyrillic, ...).
If you have already encountered problems, this might mean that the encoding language was not UTF-8.
Save the document as a TXT-file. MS-Word will ask you to specify the encoding format.  SELECT UTF-8.
Under Windows, rename the extension "txt" into "srt" if you want to make a Russian subtitle file.
If not, leave it like this.
Open your Notepad program.  FROM the Notepad MENU, select the TXT-file that you have just saved with MS-Word.  Just beside the "open" button, you have the possibility to choose the encoding format; select UTF-8.
You should be able to read the Russian text as you saw it with MS-Word.

Answer (score 0):

just select

> Encoding in UTF-8

from Encoding menu , you are ready to go

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idNZ0.png)